# java optimizer with support for compile time function evaluation

Tags: java, optimization

Is there any optimizer (free or commercial) that supports compile-time function evaluation (CTFE, aka compile-time function execution), when arguments are known at compile time and it has no side effects?

Simple example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HtmlDiv div = new HtmlDiv("test");
        System.out.println(div);
    }
}

class HtmlDiv {

    public final String text;

    public HtmlDiv(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "<div>" + text /* in real life, escape would be used */ + "</div>";
    }
}
```

This can be optimized to:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("<div>test</div>");
    }
}
```

Main reason I ask, as is seen from example, it would be nice to use static typing for my servlets (possibly with nicer syntax, such as ceylong language for jvm), but there is big difference between one println() and computing text for each html element separately. However, there are surely many more examples where it would be useful.

I tried ProGuard, but it didn't optimize. I googled around, but didn't find any optimizer that would support it. I also tried reading links from http://proguard.sourceforge.net/alternatives.html but none of optimizers mentioned on their website compile-time function evaluation, only other optimizations, e.g. dead code elimination.

Comment: How would that work? If someone changed your `HtmlDiv` class at runtime (class loading time), you'd still use the pre-calculated (and therefore wrong) value.

Comment: I don't use any runtime class changing library, ever.

Comment: When you check your code for the optimization, are you checking the compiled code from java.exe or just the compiled bytecode from javac.exe?

Comment: @peenut Others do though. And of course anyone can recompile one of the classes, deploy it and expect the rest to refer to the new class. Either way it would violate half the JLS, so no, there isn't one.

Comment: @biziclop The question was about optimizing my code, that I know it cannot be referenced from elsewhere through reflection/strings because it's not library, that's simply not possible.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove I check output *.jar file from optimizer with java decompiler, to be sure.

Comment: @peenut If it's just about your code, you can do whatever you want at compilation time so long as the result is valid byte code the JVM is capable of running. I merely explained why no such libraries exist within Java, i.e. they would be incompatible with the JLS. The other main reason is that a lot of these optimisations are done at runtime anyway, you'd gain very little in most cases.

Comment: @biziclop that's why I asked about program - optimizer - not about library. I understand this kind of optimization *might* be done by JVM (in theory), but e.g. for servlet java hosting I might not have control over what JVM is used, and this optimization is doable at compile time, as provided with example.

Comment: @peenut Fair enough, and of course I can see how it would be useful in this case. I just don't think anyone has done this in Java, I certainly haven't heard of anything similar. All the code transformer tools I know about (like ProGuard) transform classes 1-to-1 (except when the class is completely unused and left out), and only methods may be inlined.